# Smartphone Location Data Keyword Search

Tags: geolocation

I would like to understand, given a smart phone IOS (i.e. IOS or Android),  what keywords would be helpful to understand the contours of the **default** geo-location data measurements (location \ kinetics), retention and access?

It seems Orwellian, if not 'creepy' that an OS would by default record whereabouts without the user opting-in and agreeing to ***GPS smartphone location*** measurements.

Comment: *"It seems Orwellian, if not 'creepy' that an OS would by default record whereabouts without the user opting-in and agreeing to measurements."* - I think you (unfortunately) have the wrong expectations here. Recording and tracking users without consents is fairly common if you surf the web since the majority of sites run ads which track the user without any opt-in or notification (at least outside EU). Same with ad-support applications on phones.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich   You are (unfortunately for the public) right.  I should have specified, *location* measurements and not measurements in general.  Thanks for the feedback

Comment: I'm not really sure what kind of details you actually want but searching for [track user location without permission](https://www.google.com/search?q=track+user+location+without+permission) provides lots of information.